question regarding probability which includes knockout fixture
In a knockout tournament, $2^n$ equally skilled players, $S_1,S_2,\dotsc,S_{2^n}$, are participating. In each round, players are divided in pair at random and winner from each pair moves in the next round. If $S_2$ reaches the semi-final, then the probability that $S_1$ wins the tournament is $1/84$. Find the value of $n$.
I thought that since $S_2$ is in the semifinal $S_1$ was not paired with $S_2$ till semifinal as otherwise it would have been eliminated but I could not move forward.

Since there are $2^{n}-1$ players other than $S_2$, and there is room for three other players in the semifinals, the probability for each of those to reach the semifinals is $\frac{3}{2^{n}-1}$. Every player reaching the semifinals has a one in four chance of winning the tournament. So $\frac{3}{2^n-1}\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{84}$, so we quickly reach the conclusion $2^n=64$; $n=6$.
We could also argue that $S_2$ has a one in four chance of winning the tournament, so the remaining players each have a $\frac{1-\frac{1}{4}}{2^n-1}=\frac{1}{84}$ chance of winning the tournament, leading to the same conslusion.

since there are 4 player in semifinals they will be paired in groups of 2 and 2 out of 4 will emerge as winner. then how does S2 has a 1 in 4 chance of winning? should it not be 2/4 = 1/2.

@DhruvSabraj of winning the tournament, I should say to make it clearer. Given that a player reaches the semifinals, they have a 1/4 probability of winning the tournament.

oh yeah now i got it thanks
